О словообразовательном разборе слова "рисунок"
Очень нужно правильно определить способ образования существительного рисунок, но не получается. Вернее, есть сомнения.
У Тихонова: рис/ун/ок.  Какой способ образование, почему выделено два суффикса?
Примечание
Морфемный разбор слов приводится на многих учебных ресурсах, а вот со словообразовательным проблемы.
Нужно указать способ словообразования, средство словообразования и производящую основу, то есть привести схему словообразования.  Но как это сделать с помощью двух суффиксов?
В словаре Ефремовой указан суффикс УН (хвастун, колдун, шатун, плывун, скакун), но  подходящего по смыслу значения нет. Да и форманта (сложного суффикса) УНОК тоже нет.
Из Сети: https://slooovo.ru/рисунок/разборы

А в чем именно сомнения?

Я дополнила вопрос о сомнениях)  Материал по разбору у Литневской https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p23_TOC_idp1657589376

Хвастаться — хвастун.

Хвастун - это лицо, а у нас предмет: плыть - плывун, ползать - ползун. Это предметы, орудия действия, значение не подходит, Сложного суффикса УНОК нет.

Вот здесь Тихонов А. Н. Словообразовательный словарь русского языка: В 2 т. (около 145 000 слов). - М., 1985. 6. Page 8. Все однокоренные слова вместе составляют одно ...даётся такой разбор. Рис- унок.

А у вас какого года словарь?

Открываем все слова с суффиксом -ун-
Там есть и десяток слов с суффиксами -ун- + -ок-:
Ползунок, Горбунок, Сосунок, ...

Но все эти слова, мало того что являются производителями действия, так еще и имеют укороченные версии
Ползун, Горбун, Сосун, ...

Это доказывает наличие в них отдельного суффикса -ун- и отдельного суффикса -ок-.
Слово же рисунок - особенное, ни на что не похожее. Оно не имеет укороченной версии, а мы знаем, что слово может иметь два суффикса, если его происхождение происходило ступенчато, сначала прибавился один суффикс, потом второй. В происхождении же слова рисунок не наблюдается ступенчатости, а это повод считать суффиксом -унок-, а не -ун- + -ок-

Да, я тоже думаю, что УНОК. Похоже на английский ing и немецкий ung. Может, тогда и морфемный состав нужно поправить? Надо сказать Тихонову с товарищами.

Что надо сказать?

Сказать, чтобы привел в соответствие морфемный словарь (ун + ок) и словообразовательный (унок).


Я могу предположить, что слово рисунок непроизводное, как и рисовать. Это видно по этимологии слов (оба слова заимствованы из польского языка в 17 веке):

Этимологический словарь
Рисова́ть. Этот глагол заимствован из польского, где rysowac — «рисовать» восходит к немецкому reissen — «чертить».
рису́нок, род. п. -нка, впервые в 1705 г., у Петра I (Смирнов 265), укр. рису́нок. Из польск. rysunek — то же от rysować «чертить» с окончанием, восходящим к нем. -ung; см. Мi. ЕW 279; Брюкнер 472 и сл.; Христиани 45.

Но при морфемном разборе мы  выделяем узнаваемые суффиксы УН и ОК, не учитывая словообразовательные связи (формально-структурный принцип разбора по Литневской).

Суффикс существительного УН  может иметь значение лица, предмета, животного, суффикс ОК — это также частотный (регулярный и продуктивный) суффикс существительного.

Другой вриант разбора — это считать УНОК уникальным словообразовательным суффиксом, если уж его нет у Ефремовой, и разбирать так: рисовать — рис/унок. Такой вариант наиболее логичен.


В украниском таких слов много. Пидрахунок, помню ржали. Оказалось остаток


Очень нужно правильно определить способ образования существительного рисунок…

Суффиксальный. Рис(овать) —> рис + унок (обычный разбор).

Я могу предположить, что слово рисунок непроизводное…

В современном русском языке — производное у всех словаристов, в т. ч. и у Тихонова.
Из его двухтомного «Словообразовательного словаря русского языка»:



Что представляет из себя у Тихонова в данном случае комплексный аффиксальный формант ун/ок — то ли сочетание интерфикса с суффиксом, то ли сочетание двух суффиксов — однозначно утверждать не берусь. Дело в том, что для обоих вариантов у него используется одинаковая форма записи. Кстати, в Викисловаре авторы статьи «Рисуночный» ун в этом слове назвали интерфиксом:
Корень: -рис-; интерфикс: -ун-; суффиксы: -оч-н; окончание: -ый.

Другой вариант разбора — это считать УНОК уникальным словообразовательным суффиксом, если уж его нет у Ефремовой…

Именно так обычно и считают. Есть такой суффикс и у Ефремовой.
Из раздела «Суффиксальная часть»  «Словаря морфем русского языка» (М., 1986) Кузнецовой и Ефремовой:



Такой подход к морфемному членению слова рисунок в лингвистике не единственный. Есть и другая точка зрения. Вот как, к примеру, она изложена у Филипповой Л.С. в её пособии «Современный русский язык. Морфемика. Словообразование» (М., 2009):



Но, повторюсь, наиболее распространённая всё же сейчас точка зрения на морфемное членение слова рисунок — корень РИС + суффикс УНОК + нулевое окончание.

Sharon: «Всю нужную информацию мне уже сообщили, приведя всего лишь одну ссылку. И всё уже обсудили. Кстати, словечко польского происхождения (17 век), почему его здесь "пилят" на морфемы?) Вот что мне особенно интересно. И словарь другой купите, очень рекомендую: "Толковый словарь словообраз. частиц русского языка" Ефремовой 1996 год. У вас морфемный словарь, а нужен словообразовательный. И еще интересно соответствие суффиксов: русского унок и иноязычных ing, ung. Но вы про это ничего не знаете, я полагаю». ===  Господи, откуда ж столько желчи?.. Отвечу на Ваши вопросы, но позже.

Действительно. откуда? Почему вы, если это вы, меня здесь уже 8 лет преследуете. Только на мои вопросы отвечаете, хотя вопросов на форуме  бывает много.  И чем вы вообще недовольны, вежливо спрашиваю. А вот вы со своим другом мои ответы чушью называли, а меня псевдоэкспертом.  Да и сейчас оценочные суждения высказываете, нарушая правила. Припомните все это пожалуйста. Больше вам ни слова, не хочу на вас время тратить, не надо писать ответы.

"А вот вы со своим другом мои ответы чушью называли, а меня псевдоэкспертом." - А где тут нарушение правил? Это не оскорбление же.

Sharon: «И словарь другой купите, очень рекомендую: "Толковый словарь словообраз. ЧАСТИЦ русского языка" Ефремовой 1996 год». ===
ТАКОГО словаря в природе не существует! Если Вы имели в виду «Толковый словарь словообразовательных ЕДИНИЦ русского языка», то он у меня есть, только не 1996-го, а 2005 года (2-е издание, исправленное).

Слово «рисунок» образовано суффиксальным способом от глагольной основы «рисовать» (глагол → существительное).
Суффикс -ун- в слове выполняет функцию образования существительного от глагола (действие или результат действия).
Суффикс -ок придаёт оттенок завершённости и результативности действия (в данном случае — это конкретный продукт действия рисования).
Такое выделение двух суффиксов подтверждается тем, что в других похожих словах, как «черновик» (от «чернить») или «прыжок» (от «прыгать»), также можно наблюдать комбинацию суффиксов, формирующую существительное.

Серж, комбинация суффиксов  — это один сложный суффикс, тогда надо выделять УНОК, Но такого  суффикса у Ефремовой нет.  Суффикса ОВИК у нее тоже нет, поэтому: черный — черновой — черновик.
